# -1.2V from LM337L negative regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator

Here is the datasheet for this device: [TI LM337L](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm337l.pdf), at the 3rd page there is an equation for calculating the resistor needed in the voltage divider to set the output.

-Vout = -1.25 * (1 + (R2 / 240))

The 1st thing that I'm wondering about is the value of the lower resistor (240 Ohm), I could not find an explanation for this in the datasheet so I'm assuming that its a minimum value for R1 + R2 to limit the current into the device.

However, solving the equation makes it impossible to reach -1.2V:
-1.2 = -1.25 * (1 + (R2 / R1)) => (R2 / R1) < 0

The value of 1.25V is the typical reference voltage, this value goes from 1.2V to 1.3V. So if I'm understanding this correctly... If I'm lucky to have a device with a low reference voltage of 1.2V and I will short R2 so that R2/240 => 0 I can have the output voltage equal to the reference voltage and still maintain a good working environment for the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have R2  = 0. The reason for R1 = 240 \$\Omega\$ if to guarantee an minimum current of nominally 1.25/240 = 5.2mA.

This is **typically** enough to keep the output voltage from going out of regulation,  but worst case with 40V in is 10mA so it's not guaranteed to stay in regulation with no external load.

[image]

Chances are the reference voltage on your unit will be rather close to the typical value of 1.250- the outside limits are very rarely approached in a well controlled semiconductor process.

The TI TPS7A3301 series is guaranteed to get down to 1.2V.

Comment: Too bad that device does not compare in price at all.